# Regular Express for ignoring white-space-only tokens

Tags: java, regex

I am not expert in regular expression, wondering if anyone can help me here:

I want to split the following string:

```
04/16/2015 14:01:58.819   (27327) [ERR] [SYSTEM CALL]  SOCKET BIND port=4664: Address already in use [tsocket:820]
```

into the following 5 tokens:

```
04/16/2015 14:01:58.819
27327
ERR
SYSTEM CALL
SOCKET BIND port=4664: Address already in use [tsocket:820]
```

The following Java code does it for me, using regular expression `[()\\[\\]]` but it is **inefficient**!

```
List<String> splitline(String line) {
    List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
    int numToks = 0;
    line = line.trim();
    //Question 1: Change regular expression to remove white-space-only tokens!!
    String[] rawToks = line.split("[()\\[\\]]");
    for (String t : rawToks) {
        String token = t.trim();
        if (!token.isEmpty()) {
            if (numToks < 4) {
                tokens.add(token);
            }
            numToks++;
        }
    }
    //Question 2: Can the regular express be enhanced to eliminate this step?
    //In case the last required token contains () or [] then there will be more than 5 tokens,
    //so split by the 4th token (with [] around it) & use the 2nd token from the result
    if (numToks > 4) {
        tokens.add(line.split("\\[" + tokens.get(3) + "\\]")[1].trim());
    }
    return tokens;
}
```

Does anyone have answers for the 2 questions embedded in the code above?

**EDIT:**

The following code answers both questions above, thanks to accepted answer below!

```
List<String> splitline(String line) {
    return Arrays.asList(line.trim().split("[)\\]]?\\s+[(\\[]|]\\s+", 5)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

```
return Arrays.asList(line.split("[)\\]]?\\s+[(\\[]|]\\s+"));
```

Explanation:

This regular expression matches one of two possibilities:

1. An optional closing bracket/parenthesis, followed by spaces, followed by an opening bracket/parenthesis.
2. A closing bracket followed by spaces.

The first option matches the following in your string:

```
04/16/2015 14:01:58.819   (27327) [ERR] [SYSTEM CALL]  SOCKET BIND port=4664: Address already in use
                       ^^^^     ^^^   ^^^
```

And the second option matches the part after "SYSTEM CALL".

This means the line will be split **without any empty tokens**.

**Edit:**

To avoid brackets/parentheses being matched in your last field, when you know you are only interested in separating 5 fields, simply change the above to:

```
return Arrays.asList(line.split("[)\\]]?\\s+[(\\[]|]\\s+",5));
```

[`String.split(String regex, int limit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)) is a version of `String.split()` that will not look beyond `limit` tokens. That is, even if the last token includes a potential match, it will not be tested and the whole remaining string will be in the fifth token.

Comment: Thanks! This solved the first problem, I've updated the code in the question. Unfortunately the 5th token I need may also contain `[]`, as in my updated sample string in the question, so the 2nd problem still remains. :)

Comment: @PrasantaBehera I edited my answer for your 2nd problem as well.

Comment: Oops! I was idiotic not to have notice the 2nd form of split() method!

Answer (score 1):

```
\\s*[()\\[\\]]\\s*
```

You can simply split by this and remove the empty split parts by using `not None` or `not empty` whichever is available in java.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nS2lT4/6

Answer (score 0):

Just split the string according to the below regex.

```
string.split("\\s*[(\\[)\\]]\\s*");
```

This would split on `[` or `]` or `(` or `)` symbols along with the preceding or following optional spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a very standard line format, that each line is going to be with similar format and is going to be 5 tokens.

If it is the case, using `split` is not a very good idea.  Why not simply use capture group and get contents of that 5 groups out?

```
String input = "04/16/2015 14:01:58.819   (27327) [ERR] [SYSTEM CALL]  SOCKET BIND port=4664: Address already in use [tsocket:820]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(.*) *\\((\\d*)\\) \\[(.*?)\\] \\[(.*?)\\] *(.*)$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
System.out.println("matches? " + m.matches());
for (int i = 0; i < m.groupCount(); i++) {
    System.out.println(m.group(i+1));
}
```

Comment: Did not work, received error `matches? false
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
 at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:497)`

Comment: Are you sure? Unless your input is of a different format.  I have made sure the code works and just copied and paste here.  Here is my result: `matches? true<NEWLINE>
04/16/2015 14:01:58.819   <NEWLINE>
27327<NEWLINE>
ERR<NEWLINE>
SYSTEM CALL<NEWLINE>
SOCKET BIND port=4664: Address already in use`

Comment: Just updated my code with your latest example, with some minor change in the regex.  Work flawless on my side. Am interested to know what went wrong on your side.